# Indy is altering the binary data in my URL

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I want to send some binary data over via `GET` using the Indy components.
So, I have an URL like  www.awebsite.com/index.php?data=xxx where xxx is the binary data encoded using `ParamsEncode` function. After encoding the binary data is converted to something like `bB7%18%11z\` so my URL is something like:
`www.awebsite.com/bB7%18%11z\`

I have seen that if my URL contains the backshash char (see the last char in the URL) it is replaced with slash char (/) in `TIdURI.NormalizePath` so my binary data is corrupted. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Backslashes aren't allowed in URL's, and to avoid confusion between Windows and *nix systems, all backslashes are replaced by slashes to attempt to keep things working. See http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738.html section 5, HTTP, httpurl

You could try with replacing backslashes with `%5C` yourself.

That said, you should either try with MIME encoding, or try to get a hang of POST requests.

Comment: Thanks Stijn. If \ is not allowed, then why isn't replaced in ParamsEncode function? Its name is misleading. There are other chars like \ that can create problems?

Comment: I will implement a function called ParamsEncodeAlsoBackSlash :)

Answer (score 2):

You're using an old version of Indy. Backslashes are included in the `UnsafeChars` list that Indy uses now. Remy changed it in July 2010 with revision 4272 in the Tiburon branch:

> r4272 | Indy-RemyLebeau | 2010-07-07 03:12:23 -0500 (Wed, 07 Jul 2010) | 1 line
>
> Internal logic changes for TIdURI, and moved some sharable logic into IdGlobalProtocols.pas for later use in TIdHTTP.

It was merged into the trunk with the rest of Indy 10.5.7 with revision 4394, in September 2010.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I am using the latest version (10.203 or 10.2.3) of Indy that works with D7.

Comment: Dennis Passmore says [he can compile revision 4511 in Delphi 7](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=48622). Otherwise, just apply the change from 4272.

Comment: PS: I think you mean v4611: "Just a follow up to this thread since I had not check it for a while but I just downloaded, built and installed Indy10_4611.zip with no more problems using Delphi 7"   :)

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot for that link. All I need now its to find that package :)

Comment: No need to find the package; get it straight from SVN: `svn co -r 4611 https://svn.atozed.com:444/svn/Indy10`